# Order of instances in 3D Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d

I'm making cube of 9 cubes in Flash As3. However i cant rotate it properly due to order of indexes whole adding then to stage.
First im creating cube of 6 squares, then wall of 9 cubes, and at the end cube of 3 walls.
It is all fine, however when i rotate it to the left, order of cubes is inverted and it ruins whole composition. I know i coul dinamicly change index based on rotation but it would be a loooooooot of work.
Any ideas how could i do it better way?

Here is actual model:
 http://test.mrowa.topdivision.pl/kostka/3DTest.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Flash's display list you would have to sort the sprites based on their z.

Here is some code that would sort the children of a `DisplayObjectContainer` based on their z position, call this whenever some object changes its position.

```
public function sortChildren(container:DisplayObjectContainer):void
{
    var objects:Vector.<DisplayObject> = new Vector.<DisplayObject>;

    for (var i:int = 0; i < container.numChildren; i++) 
    {
        objects.push(container.getChildAt(i));
    }

    objects.sort(sortCompare);

    var index:int = 0;
    for (var j:int = 0; j < objects.length; j++) 
    {
            index = container.getChildIndex(objects[j]);
            if (index != j)
                container.setChildIndex(objects[j], j);         
    }
}

private function sortCompare(a:DisplayObject, b:DisplayObject):int
{
    return (a.z - b.z);
}
```

You can move the `objects` member to be a class member and add/remove items to it whenever you add/remove items to/from the stage so that you don't have to fill the whole array every time this function is called.

Comment: But does rotating change single instances' Z position? And what exactly should be sprites Array? because i get "Display object must be a children of calling object" error all the time.

Comment: Rotating doesn't change the z position. Edited my answer `sprites` array was `objects`. The way you would call this function is by sending in the container that has all the sprites thay you want to sort ie. `sortChildren(myContainerSprite);`

Comment: It says something weird.
"Cannot find s1 in cube"
why does it look in cube, if i give him container of wall (stage or this)?
PS.: s1 is a name of cube instance
ok that was my bad. It is other part of code which says that

Comment: Not sure why it would give that error. Try to debug and see which container you pass in and the children are correct.

Comment: Ok. It seems to work partially. It sorts out well. However just for a frame, and at second frame it sorts out again and display order is wrong, wich makes effect of blinking at intersecting bounds of cubes.

Comment: Yeah. As i thought its because they all still got z = 0
And i only rotate the cube. Tahnks for effort thought